# Flot charts, turning 'points' options on or off

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Im using flotcharts.org to present some data on my site and I would like to turn the option points on or off(true or false) with a click, checkbox or a button. Here is a example when point is on(true): http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/basic-options/index.html

Comment: And what is your problem implementing that example?

Comment: Im pretty new to javascript and jquery. I have no problem setting the options when I hardcode them, but I don't know how to change them 'on click'. This is my code right now: https://pastie.se/14b115ca

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest example I can code up:

```
var plot = null;
drawChart = function(showPoints) {
    plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ], {
               series: {
                    lines: { show: true },
                    points: { show: showPoints }
               }
            });
}

drawChart(false);

$('#button').click(function(){
   drawChart(!plot.getOptions().series.points.show );        
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RKe2u/1/)